# How to delete the default turtle that is created using turtlesim in ros?

Tags: rosservice, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I proceed to do that? I would like to use

```
rosservice call /kill " 'name_of_the_turtle' "
```

Where do I find the name of the turtle?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311579/how-to-delete-the-default-turtle-that-is-created-using-turtlesim-in-ros?/) by [aakashg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26136/aakashg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-12-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [turtlesim docs](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlesim) are not specific about the turtle name, but it looks like the turtle names are either their number, or `turtle` followed by the number (`turtleN`), so I'd start by trying both of those to see if either works.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-12-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1